# Ruby date equation not returning expected truth value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Why do the following differ?

```
Time.now.end_of_day      == Time.now.end_of_day - 0.days      # false
Time.now.end_of_day.to_s == Time.now.end_of_day - 0.days.to_s # true
```

Comment: What does `Time.now.end_of_day.to_s == Time.now.end_of_day.to_s - ((1 - 1) * 7).days.to_s` return than? Or maybe `Time.now.end_of_day.to_s == ( Time.now.end_of_day - ((1 - 1) * 7).days).to_s`

Comment: @Phrogz, that does not fix it. I think Jorge is right, you have to use `to_i`.

Comment: @Mischa How interesting; thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the number of nanoseconds is different:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :014 > (Time.now.end_of_day - 0.days).nsec
 => 999999000 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :015 > Time.now.end_of_day.nsec
 => 999999998
```

Comment: I'd personally consider that a bug in `#end_of_day`.  Nanoseconds exist, sure, but if end_of_day is a few nanoseconds from the end of the day, then it's not, ermm, the end of the day ;)

Comment: But when you subtract 0.days from it, it is even further from the end of the day. So if there is a bug it is rather in `days` than in `end_of_day`.

Answer (score 3):

Like Mischa said, the times differ by nanoseconds. [Here](http://blog.tddium.com/2011/08/07/rails-time-comparisons-devil-details-etc/) is an article on workarounds and fixes for doing this in Rails, specifically for tests like you are doing.

The seemingly most straightforward approach given is to round the times to seconds by appending `.to_i`, but there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Mischa's answer:

From the [docs on the Time object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html): "All times may have fraction. Be aware of this fact when comparing times with each other—times that are apparently equal when displayed may be different when compared."

So your first calculation compares two Time objects, which are different at the nanosecond level, but your second calculation converts both Time objects to Strings, which ignores the nanoseconds and returns true because both String representations match.